# idea/workspace.xml deleted, can not start project on intelliJ

Tags: xml, git, intellij-idea

this is my first question on stackoverflow.

a team member deleted .idea/workspace.xml on my macbook pro.
afterwards i couldn't start the same project on intellij, so i deleted the project folder and cloned the project, but it doesn't start anymore..

there is this note:

[intelliJ note:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL7Sg.png)

Answer (score 0):

are you using gradle? if yes, try:

```
gradle cleanIdea idea
```